# VirtulaBox bridge not working with ADSL modem but only works with NAT

Tags: networking, ubuntu, virtualbox, adsl-router

I use Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 and ADSL internet.

I have VirtualBox and use a virtual Windows 10 there. The network setting is set to NAT when I am connected to ADSL. If I change it to Bridge, it doesn't work and Windows does not have any internet connection.

But if I change my internet connection to my mobile phone (using Hotspot) and get connected to the mobile, I should change the network settings from NAT to Bridge mode.

I want to use Bridge mode when I am connected to ADSL. What should I do? Should I change any settings in modem settings? I mean 192.168.1.1.

**Update 1**

As an example, I want to connect to a VPN in Ubuntu but I don't want Windows's IP changes. I want to have my ADSL IP in Windows and have VPN IP in Linux (it's possible with mobile hotspot with Bridge, but not possible with ADSL Modem).

***PG69 update***

When the VM is configured with static IP, the connection works also with the ADSL router. The router is Zyxel DEL1312-T10B, and DHCP is enabled with settings correspond to what [the manual](http://dl.shatel.ir/StaticContent/uploads/Image/pdf/rtl/04GL78.pdf) (in Farsi) shows:

[image: LAN settings]

Comment: Are you bridging it to the right adapter?

Comment: @mully yes I'm sure

Comment: @mully I just added an update to clarify the reason I asked this question.

Comment: Does your Ubuntu box get an IP address from the modem, or did yo configure static? If you put the VM to bridged mode and configure static IP (for example 192.168.1.100 255.255.255.0) can it ping the modem's 192.168.1.1? If yes, can it ping 1.1.1.1? If last one is "yes" it has internet access.

Comment: @Peregrino69 1) Ubuntu's IP is dynamic and DHCP. 2)I tried static IP in VM and it's working:) But if I change my internet connection to mobile hotspot, I should change static IP to dynamic in VM (IP ranges are different. ADSL is 192.168.1.1/24 and mobile is 192.168.43.1/24). This solution is good, but is there a better solution?

Comment: It's not a solution yet, just a workaround and first step in finding one :-) Next step would be logging into the modem's management interface and checking the DHCP settings. However I'd like to know what the modem exactly is. I'd like to check what I can find out about it, makes it easier to describe further steps :-)

Comment: @Peregrino69 the modem model is Zyxel DEL1312-T10B. I see that DHCP is enabled.

Comment: ... didn't expect an Arabic manual :-D One last question: do you connect through wire or Wi-Fi?

Comment: @Peregrino69 I connect through Wi-Fi. I think you're seeing a Persian (Farsi) manual. I'm Iranian and if your findings are in Persian I can read it:) If they're in another language, Google Translate helps us.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129959/discussion-between-peregrino69-and-saeed).